# How to get rid of the following error? Converting date from string is failed

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I am getting the error:

> Error -2147217913: Conversion failed when converting date an/or time from character string.

[Error in converting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgRtg.jpg)

I am sure that my fields are in date field, but why this error keeps on showing?

First I validated first if the data type is really a date column:

```
 CASE 
    WHEN ISDATE(dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo.UserDefined2) = 1 
       THEN dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo.UserDefined2 
       ELSE NULL 
 END AS ReceivedDate
```

I found out that yes, it's correct. so i proceed with converting this field where UserDefined2 value should always be plus 1 day.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo.UserDefined2)), 103) AS ReceivedDate
```

Please let me know if there's something wrong with my query as I really can't diagnose what went wrong.

See screenshot:

[See this link, the actual data and in SQL server + 1 day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnhJU.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide sample data in `dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo.UserDefined2` column?

Comment: I have edited the question by providing the screenshot thanks heaps!

Comment: Weird your query works just fine when I tested it.

Comment: Yes it's weird, I have attached the error in my question. :( CurseStacker

Comment: The error message isn't "in SQL Server", it's in a custom application. Where is your expression going to be used? Who will execute a query that uses this expression and what are the language settings for that login?

Comment: Can you provide the application code that generates this error when you click on the selection (like how you did in the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the field is indeed a date field, so it could be that no conversion is required. Try `DATEADD(DAY, 1, dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo.UserDefined2)`.

If the column is indeed a string column, the you forgot to specify the *style* parameter when reading the value, you only used it when converting back. Try this instead:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo.UserDefined2, 103)), 103) AS ReceivedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says that date, time and datetime types are not allowed as arguments to ISDATE but in practical terms, passing a date to it:

```
SELECT ISDATE(getutcdate())
```

Causes the datetime to be converted to varchar implicitly, passed to ISDATE as varchar, which promptly then returns a 1

As such we've no guarantee that your column really is a date type like you say, so I'm guessing it's probably a string.

Really, what you should do is change your column to be a date type. Don't store dates as strings; if Microsoft had intended you to do this and thought for a second it was a good idea, they wouldn't have implemented other column types than char based ones

If you cannot convert your column to date then you'll need to find the bad value:

```
select * from table where isdate(column) =0
```

Note that your attempt to convert style 103 (dd/mm/yyyy) may be failing because you have data that isn't in this style eg Christmas as 12/25/2000

Isdate might not pick this up because your database date format is set to mm/dd/yyyy and isdate thinks it's ok. Change your database date format so that isdate can properly tell what is a good date and what is a bad date

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

And then, please, for the love of doing this properly, use a date typed column, not a string typed one

Answer (score 0):

We need more information. In particular, we need to know what data type the UserDefined2 is. If you tell us that, then we can give better replies.

Just a note that ISDATE is a pretty worthless function since it returns 1 if the string is convertible to datetime. But what if what you really have os datetime2? Or smalldatetime? Because of that, use TRY_CAST instead.

Also, you just gave us pieces of queries, expressions. We don't see the context. There is something called predicate pushing in SQL Server that can mess things up for you (SQL Server pushes a predicate deeper into the query resulting that an expression work over non-datetime values even though you *think* that you have excluded them in a WHERE clause.

Also, note that how a datetime value is interpreted when you have separators and use the old types (datetime or datetime2) depends on the login's language setting.

More info in http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes